# HTML select when click the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, selected

I have a little problem. I have a select of an html page, when I select it often happens that the selection of the mouse remains locked and when I move my mouse I select all the content of the page.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please provide link of that page than i help you.

Comment: It sounds like you're double clicking the select, which in turn is selecting the elements surrounding the select.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that contains the rows and cells.

In the cell I have a DropDownList that load on the server (I'm using ASP.NET) unseen. The DDL is rendered in an HTML Select.

When I click the cell with iquery.show () I display the select and to make it selectable I jquery.focus ().

When I click the select button to bring out the option, sometimes (not always) the mouse I select all in the browser.

On the page I have some javascript functions

> $(".ddlClassAttivita").on("click", (function (events) {
>
> //Mycode
>   }));
>
> $(".ddlClassAttivita").on("change", (function (events) {
>
> //Mycode 
>   }));

I apologize for the English but I'm using translate